# Problems with Avro deserialization in Kafka sink connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to read data from DB2 using Kafka and then to write it to HDFS. I use distributed confluent platform with standard JDBC and HDFS connectors. 
As the HDFS connector needs to know the schema, it requires avro data as an input. Thus, I have to specify the following avro converters for the data fed to Kafka (in etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties):

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```

I then run my JDBC connector and check with the console-avro-consumer that I can successfully read the data fetched from the DB2.

However, when I launch the HDFS Connector, it does not work anymore. Instead, it outputs SerializationException:

```
Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
... Unknown magic byte!
```

To check if this is a problem with the HDFS connector, I tried to use a simple FileSink connector instead. However, I saw exactly the same exception when using the FileSink (and the file itself was created but stayed empty).

I then carried out the following experiment: Instead of using avro converter for the key and value I used json converters:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schema.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schema.enable=false
```

This fixed the problem with the FileSink connector, i.e., the whole pipeline from DB2 to the file worked fine. However, for the HDFS connector this solution is infeasible as the connector needs the schema and consequently avro format as an input.

It feels to me that the deserialization of avro format in the sink connectors is not implemented properly as the console-avro-consumer can still successfully read the data.
Does anyone have any idea of what could be the reason of this behavior? I'd also appreciate an idea of a simple fix for this!

Answer (score 2):

> check with the console-avro-consumer that I can successfully read the data fetched

I'm guessing you didn't add `--property print.key=true --from-beginning` when you did that.

Its possible that the latest values are Avro, but connect is clearly failing somewhere on the topic, so you need to scan it to find out where that happens

If using `JsonConverter` works, and the data is actually readable JSON on disk, then it sounds like the JDBC Connector actually wrote JSON, not Avro

If you are able to pinpoint the offset for the bad message, you can use the regular console consumer with the connector group id set, then add `--max-messages` along with a partition and offset specified to skip those events

Comment: I did also try to add --property print.key=true and I saw null for the key. After that I tried to use StringConverter but it didn't change anything - I got exactly the same exception.

Comment: Were you consuming from the beginning of the topic? And you're sure you're using the Avro consumer? Because your error is coming from the deserializer which is shared by the console consumer and the AvroConverter in Connect, so you should be seeing the same problem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

1. Yes, when I used JsonConverter, the connector actually wrote JSON into the file - sorry for being imprecise with that.

2. I believe, I consumed from the beginning of the topic. The exact command I tried was:
./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server node1:9093,node2:9093,node3:9093 --topic my-offsets --property print.key=true --consumer.config ./etc/auth-client.properties (here auth-client.properties contains some SASL configuration settings)

Comment: That'll consume from the latest, current offset until you add `--from-beginning`, but I wouldn't expect your data to change types mid-topic unless someone produced a random message into the topic (by mistake?)

Comment: That is a very good point, thank you for this! I tried the `--from-beginning` option with the console-avro-consumer and it suddenly crashed with the same avro deserializing exception (unknown magic byte) as I saw when using hdfs or file sinks. This confuses me a lot as the data comes from the same table (I just specify a select query against the table in my JDBC connector). Would you have any idea of why could the data change its type in this case? Could this happen due to missing data or smth?

Comment: I'm guessing somebody produced a regular string onto the topic somewhere... You can use the regular console consumer then look at messages that don't look like the others